# How to add first 30 chars of a .txt file to a variable?

Tags: python, string, variables, character, addition

So I have this homework question:

Assign the first 30 characters of `school_prompt.txt` as a **string** to the variable `beginning_chars`.

In the previous problem I managed to count all the characters in the txt file but I don't know how to add the first 30 into a variable.

```
fname = "school_prompt.txt"
lines = 0
nwords = 0
beginning_chars = 0 
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line >= 30:
            words = line.split()
            lines +=1 
            nwords += len(words)
            beginning_chars += len(line)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
fname = "school_prompt.txt"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    beginning_chars = f.read(30)
```

The `read` method can take the number of bytes to read as an argument. In most encodings one byte will equal one character.